# Buttons and input fields not responding to mouse events

Tags: html, css

I have this html and css code. http://jsfiddle.net/Pp9Z6/

I can't figure out why I'm not able to click inside the `EditText` and `Button` widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click the edit, and choose 'inspect element', you know why. The element that you're inspecting turns out to be a div. It's because div 'main-nav' is an overlay over almost the entire page.

And that is due to this CSS:

```
div {
    position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;
    display: table;
}
```

You could solve it by adding `z-index: -1;` to that CSS, but the real question is why that div is there in the first place. There's probably a better way to align your main navigation. Actually, it seems to work just fine (or at least the same) when I remove that entire CSS definition: http://jsfiddle.net/Pp9Z6/2/

Comment: So what should it be? (I'm a complete html/css beginner)

Comment: It looks different, the banner isnt centered, and the menu items arent either.

Answer (score 0):

You have a gigantic div that keeps you from clicking the input, or the button... I strongly advise your to review you page layout, but if you want to solve this praticular problem, wrap the login area to a div, and set its `position` to relative. It will get in front of the #main-nav

http://jsfiddle.net/Pp9Z6/3/

Comment: You've got the right div, but I don't know where you get the z-index from.

Comment: Sorry. The `z-index` is set to the `<li>`s inside the div. I'll edit the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove `height:100%` rule form your `div` style. It is overlapping your entire page.

Answer (score -1):

```
div {
position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;
display: table;
```

}

above div Overlapping the rest of the content. so u can't access element
just remove `position:absolute;`  and see it will work or modify the code as below

```
    div {
position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;
display: table;
z-index:-1;
```

}